# QtPy5 GridLayout Row Resizing

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a program that dynamically adds rows to a form when you press a button to add. There is another button to remove them. Adding works (and resizes correctly), but when I delete them, it only recovers some of the space. The buttons recenter themselves on the available space rather than my filter container shrinking back down.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# pylint: disable=missing-docstring 
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module 
# pylint: disable=unused-import 

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout,
    QGridLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        testLabel = QLabel("Placeholder")
        testLabel2 = QLabel("Placeholder")
        grid.addWidget(testLabel, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(testLabel2, 2, 0, 1, 2)
        filterContainer = FilterContainer()
        grid.addLayout(filterContainer, 1, 0, 1, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)        
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')    
        self.show()

class FilterContainer(QVBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.addRow()

    def addRow(self):
        rw = FilterRow()
        rw.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.addRow)
        self.addLayout(rw)

class FilterRow(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btnDelete = QPushButton('Delete')
        self.btnDelete.clicked.connect(self.deleteSelf)
        self.addWidget(self.btnDelete)

        self.btnAdd = QPushButton('Add')
        self.addWidget(self.btnAdd)

    def deleteSelf(self): 
        if self is not None: 
            while self.count(): 
                item = self.takeAt(0) 
                widget = item.widget() 
                if widget is not None: 
                    widget.deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: An implementation detail of QGridLayout/QFormLayout is that whenever items are deleted, the number of *logical* rows and columns will never decrease, even though the number of *visual* rows or colums may do. So you probably need to try reusing empty rows, rather than simply adding new ones all the time.

Comment: I’m not actually deleting rows from the grid. Inside the grid is another layout that expands with the rows, so it always just occupies one row in the grid. When I delete them that vertical layout adjusts to center it on the now taller row. I’d like that wide row to shrink back down though.

Comment: There is little point in discussing this further without a [mcve].

Comment: Fair enough. Right now the code is spread out over 5 files, most of which is completely unnecessary to show the problem so I was hoping it was simple enough it wouldn't require that. I'll make up minimal example and edit my main post this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, so I'll post here in case anyone else has the same issue. I hadn't set any rows on the grid with stretch, so I guess it was arbitrarily resizing.

By adding the line:

```
self.grid.setRowStretch(3,1)
```

it tells the row below it to stretch to fill the available space, so it shrinks the row I want back down as the rows are deleted.